# How to use Skaffold with kubernetes volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-volume, volumes, skaffold

I have an python application whose docker build takes about 15-20 minutes.
Here is how my Dockerfile looks like more or less

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
...
COPY . /usr/local/app
RUN pip install -r /usr/local/app/requirements.txt
...
CMD ...
```

Now if I use skaffold, any code change triggers a rebuild and it is going to do a reinstall of all requirements(as from the COPY step everything else is going to be rebuild) regardless of whether they were already installed. iIn docker-compose this issue would be solved using volumes. In kubernetes, if we use volumes in the following way:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: test
spec:
containers:
- image: test:test
name: test-container
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /usr/local/venv # this is the directory of the 
# virtualenv of python
    name: test-volume
volumes:
- name: test-volume
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: <volume-id>
    fsType: ext4
```

will this extra requirements build be resolved with skaffold?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for skaffold specifically but the container image build can be improved. If there is layer caching available then only reinstall the dependencies when your `requirements.txt` changes. This is documented in the "ADD or COPY" [Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
...
COPY requirements.txt /usr/local/app/
RUN pip install -r /usr/local/app/requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/local/app
...
CMD ...
```

You may need to trigger updates some times if the module versions are loosely defined and say you want a new patch version. I've found requirements should be specific so versions don't slide underneath your application without your knowledge/testing.

## Kaniko in-cluster builds

For kaniko builds to make use of a cache in a cluster where there is no persistent storage by default, kaniko needs either a persistent volume mounted (`--cache-dir`) or a container image repo (`--cache-repo`) with the layers available.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to speed up the dev process: Instead of triggering an entirely new deployment process every time you change a line of code, you can switch to a sync-based dev process to deploy once and then update the files within the running containers when editing code.

Skaffold supports **file sync to directly update files inside the deployed containers** if you change them on your local machine. However, the docs state "File sync is alpha" (https://skaffold.dev/docs/how-tos/filesync/) and I can completely agree from working with it a while ago: The sync mechanism is only one-directional (no sync from container back to local) and pretty buggy, i.e. it crashes frequently when switching git branches, installing dependencies etc. which can be pretty annoying.

If you want a **more stable alternative for sync-based Kubernetes development** which is very easy to get started with, take a look at DevSpace: https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace

I am one of the maintainers of DevSpace and started the project because Skaffold was much too slow for our team and it did not have a file sync back then.

Comment: Yes indeed, `tilt` is another tool I came across that will do the same. I am currently running some tests and POCs to  try it out https://docs.tilt.dev/live_update_tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, tilt is pretty good as well. Especially if you want to work with minikube etc. in a local cluster.

Answer (score 1):

@Matt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702674/1423507) is a great best practice (+1) - `skaffold` in and of itself won't solve the underlying layer cache invalidation issues which results in having to re-install the requirements during every build.

For additional performance, you can cache all the `python` packages in a `volume` mounted in your pod for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: test
spec:
containers:
- image: test:test
  name: test-container
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /usr/local/venv
    name: test-volume
- mountPath: /root/.cache/pip
    name: pip-cache
volumes:
- name: test-volume
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: <volume-id>
    fsType: ext4
- name: pip-cache
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: <volume-id>
    fsType: ext4
```

That way if the build cache is ever invalidated and you have to re-install your `requirements.txt` you'd be saving some time by fetching them from cache.

If you're building with [`kaniko`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) you can also cache base images to a persistent disk using the `kaniko-warmer`, for example:

```
...
volumeMounts:
...
- mountPath: /cache
    name: kaniko-warmer
volumes:
...
- name: kaniko-warmer
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: <volume-id>
    fsType: ext4
```

Running the `kaniko-warmer` inside the pod: `docker run --rm -it -v /cache:/cache --entrypoint /kaniko/warmer gcr.io/kaniko-project/warmer --cache-dir=/cache --image=python:3.7-slim --image=nginx:1.17.3`. Your `skaffold.yaml` might look something like:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta13
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: test:test
    kaniko:
      buildContext:
        localDir: {}
      cache:
        hostPath: /cache
  cluster:
    namespace: jx
    dockerConfig:
      secretName: jenkins-docker-cfg
  tagPolicy:
    envTemplate:
      template: '{{.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/{{.IMAGE_NAME}}'
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
```

Comment: If you are doing in-cluster docker builds, assuming kaniko, the same could be done with the [`--cache`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#--cache) and [`--cache-dir`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#--cache-dir) options

Comment: Can use the `--cache-dir` for `python` packages? Wasn't aware of that, I use the `kaniko-warmer` to cache base images in a `--cache-dir` (also backed by a persistent disk), will have to test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I worded my comment badly.  You don't use `cache-dir` specifically for python packages but using the same `mountPath` setup for a kaniko cache dir, kaniko can cache container image layers. Once you have the Dockerfile setup from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702674/1318694) the initial `requirements.txt` and `pip install` layers can be pulled from local disk cache when the contents haven't changed.

Comment: Actually with a multistage build you could have a cached image with the pip cache in it. Then the final image can stay clean, just copying the file paths you want.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I use `kaniko` / `kaniko-warmer` (`jenkins x` with `tekton` pipelines) for my builds - updated my answer. Didn't think about the multi-stage build but that is a good point, e.g. build an image with just the dependencies following best practices, cache the image for extending them with the `kaniko-warmer`, if you need to rebuild them then cache the dependencies (i.e. pip-cache). Seems legit.

Comment: Latest version(s) of `nexus` supports proxying / caching `apt` repositories (as well as many other things i.e. `npm`, `pypi`, `docker`, ...). `squid` can be used as a pull through cache proxy as well. Same for the `docker` registry to avoid having to pull images from the internetz all the time as per the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/).

Comment: @masseyb I tried your solution with kaniko, but ```skaffold dev``` is failing with the following message:
```listing files: undefined artifact type: {DockerArtifact:<nil> BazelArtifact:<nil> JibMavenArtifact:<nil> JibGradleArtifact:<nil> KanikoArtifact:0xc00030bb90 CustomArtifact:<nil>}```
Not sure what is going on!